# Add a new column based on the current time

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm using sqlite3 with Python. I would like to select the closest time from the current time while listing the classrooms. This is [timetable] database.

```
     [ timetable ]
lecture_room start_time
---------------------
A211         13:00
A211         14:00
B107         13:00
```

If I query when the current time is 11:34, the expected results are as follows. (I would like one classroom to be queried only once.)

```
lecture_room next_time
---------------------
A211         13:00
B107         13:00
```

If I query when the current time is 13:34, the expected results are as follows.

```
lecture_room next_time
---------------------
A211         14:00
B107         <null>
```

This is my SQL Query that I coded, but this SQL query makes error (`[1] [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such column: L)`)

```
SELECT lecture_room as L,
  (SELECT MIN(start_time)
   FROM timetable
   WHERE
     time("now", "localtime") <= time(start_time)
    AND
       L = lecture_room
  )
FROM timetable;
```

Comment: "   AND  L = lecture_room" makes no sense, as it's the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get only one entry for each room, use DISTINCT (in a subquery, otherwise it would apply to both columns).

The [correlated subquery](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#cosub) is almost correct; you have to refer to the correct table:

```
SELECT lecture_room,
       (SELECT min(start_time)
        FROM timetable AS t2
        WHERE t2.lecture_room = t1.lecture_room
          AND t2.start_time >= time('now', 'localtime')
       ) AS next_time
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT lecture_room
      FROM timetable) AS t1;
```

Comment: Really, really, really thank you very mucy.. works like a charm.... :D Have a nice day!!